# If foreign key exists, drop it

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, exists, sql-drop

I have a table that has a foreign key relation with another table.

I want to check that if this relation exists, drop it.

How to I write this query.

Thanks.

Comment: which database management system are you using? oracle, mssql, postgre, etc.?

Comment: There is no standardized way to do that, but each DBMS has its own - please answer Gambrinus's question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, this should works

```
if exists (select 1 from sys.objects where object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[FKName]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('TableName'))
  alter table TableName drop constraint FKName
```